# Create many objects of same kind when array of objects is not allowed

Tags: c++, arrays, string, object

I have an class that doesn't allow array of objects of same kind created.

Ex:
`Canvas c;` 
I can't create `Canvas c[5]`.

Is it possible I can modify the string c by somewhere outside i.e. append `c` with `i` and loop over and should be able to place after `Canvas`.

String manipulation part to generate `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`.

Can I put these after `Canvas`?

Here's the same code:

```
//C++ Headers
#include <iostream>

//ROOT Headers
#include <TCanvas.h>


using namespace std;

void CanvasArray(){
    TCanvas c[5] = new TCanvas("c[5]", "", 400, 500); 
    for (int i; i<5; i++)
        c[i]->Draw();

}
```

And, the output:

```
Processing CanvasArray.C...
Error: Can't call TCanvas::TCanvas((class TCanvas*)0x98d76a8) in current scope CanvasArray.C:12:
Possible candidates are...
(in TCanvas)
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 private: TCanvas TCanvas::TCanvas(const TCanvas& canvas); //cannot copy canvas, use TObject::Clone()
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 public: TCanvas Canvas::TCanvas(Bool_t build=kTRUE);
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 public: TCanvas TCanvas::TCanvas(const char* name,const char* title="",Int_t form=1);
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 public: TCanvas TCanvas::TCanvas(const char* name,const char* title,Int_t ww,Int_t wh);
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 public: TCanvas TCanvas::TCanvas(const char* name,const char* title,Int_t wtopx,Int_t wtopy,Int_t ww,Int_t wh);
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/root5.34/libGpad.so  -1:-1   0 public: TCanvas TCanvas::TCanvas(const char* name,Int_t ww,Int_t wh,Int_t winid);
(in TPad)
*** Interpreter error recovered ***

[19]+  Stopped                 root -l CanvasArray.C
```

Comment: "*Is it possible I can modify the string c by somewhere outside i.e. append c with i and loop over and should be able to place after Canvas*" Huh? What do you mean by "after Canvas"? And where did strings come in to this?

Comment: @David Schwartz, I am trying to get
Canvas c1, c2, c3 ....., c100, 
but, I want the labels c1, c2.... c100 generated somewhere outside as strings, but later on put after Canvas, since I can't initialize array of that particular object.

Comment: @Pgram Is this C or C++? And why can't you initialize an array?

Comment: It can be used with C++, but it doesn't let me do that, the code breaks whenever I try to initialize it.

Comment: Paste the code that breaks. Let's fix it.

Comment: @David Schwartz, I edited the main post. Please have a look

Comment: I don't think `TCanvas c[5] = new TCanvas("c[5]", "", 400, 500);` looks right... You're trying to initialize an array of 5 objects with a single pointer to a single object. Can you just `TCanvas c[5];` to default-initialize 5 objects and then loop through them and re-initialize/modify the objects with specific values?

Comment: What do you mean it's "not allowed"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::vector`:

```
void CanvasArray(){
    std::vector<TCanvas> c;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        c.emplace_back("c[5]", "", 400, 500);
        c[i].draw();
    }   

}
```

Comment: ROOT methods are usually written with upper case initial letters. Which is also the case for `TCanvas::Draw`. So it should be `c[i].Draw();` instead of `c[i].draw();`

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you should usually avoid having different objects with the same name in ROOT. ROOT comes with the `Form` function, which works similar to the `printf` function of `C` (though it avoids a bit of `char*` declarations).

Furthermore, as said already `std::vector` is probably your friend as container class. Since your initial example uses `new` I take give here an example where I put `TCanvas*` into the container instead of `TCanvas`

```
//C++ Headers
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//ROOT Headers
#include <TCanvas.h>



void CanvasArray(){
    std::vector<TCanvas*> c;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        c.push_back(new TCanvas(Form("c%d",i), "", 400, 500));
        c[i]->Draw();
    }

}
```